# Python Package Installation: Pip Errors

Tags: python, pip

So I am a beginner at python, and I was trying to install packages using pip. But any time I try to install I keep getting the error:

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'c:\python38\Scripts\sqlformat.exe' -> 'c:\python38\Scripts\sqlformat.exe.deleteme'

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running command line as administrator. The issue looks like its about permission. To run as administrator. Type cmd on search bar and right click on icon of command prompt. There you will find an option of run as administrator. Click the option and then try to install package

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a permissions error. You might try starting the installation with admin rights or install the package only for your current user with:

```
pip install --user package
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is with permissions . Try running the same command on the terminal as a "administrator". Let me know if that fixes this issue.